# Drupal 7 CDN whitelist issue

Tags: 7, cdn

My Drupal 7 site is working nice and most of my static files are served via CDN. I use **CDN module** with **Origin Pull** however CDN didn't pull the files from my `misc` folder where there are small `png` icons (*came with vanilla drupal installation*).

In CSS, I have used `url('sites/all/themes/mytheme/img/bg.png')` for background and I can see the background, and it is served via CDN. In the same CSS I have `url('misc/configure.png')` but this one is not working. I see **404** for `configure.png` while checking from Developer Tool.

So, I added the path in CDN module's whitelist like `misc/*.png` and did all those **flushing** and **cron** for CDN to recognize the file. Still CDN didn't pull the file. I have set the file permissions to **775** too, but nothing changed. Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:** the 404 is only for the picture, I checked it via chrome's Developer tool. It shows the path `https://myCDN/misc/configure.png` (*which is missing*), whereas for background it shows `https://myCDN/mysite/sites/all/themes/mytheme/img/bg.png`.

However, the notable difference is in `configure.png` the name of my site is not present in CDN path. If I change the path via Chrome Developer Tool like `https://myCDN/mysite/misc/configure.png` It works, the image shows. It also works if I use absolute url in CSS like `url('https://mysite/misc/configure.png')`

Comment: I want to see what others say, but I think this may be a bug in the module.  I had a similar issue a few weeks ago.  I ended up *.png and *.jpg.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Could you please avoid using \`code ticks\` for things that are not in fact a code, and add link to module name? For 404, could you provide full path your browser is trying to access, using firebug or similar tool? And could you see in your access.log if CDN attempts to ever download the file at all?

Comment: @MPD I'll try that one, I guess it wouldn't be security risk if it is just images.

Comment: @Mołot those code ticks are for readability, I'll try to post with different formatting if it is confusing. I'll edit the question, as it is too long to type here what I wanted to write.

Comment: You have **bold** and *italics* for readability all right ;) And it's always preferable to edit question than to post data in comments, no matter if it's one sentence or 5 paragraphs.

Comment: "he name of my site is not present in CDN path." - if you add it manually in the browser's address bar, can you obtain the image from CDN? If so, I it's a bug in CDN module. But that hardly makes sense, to be honest.

Comment: Not in the browser's address, but if I add the url path from Developer tools, it shows the image. It also works in case of absolute URL. This means, CDN is pulling the file but not serving it, or issuing wrong url.

Comment: Please add this to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was doing the wrong practices with **Drupal Theme**, in **CSS** whenever I have to use the `url()` to declare the path, I was using `url('sites/all/themes/mytheme/images/bg.png')` which is considered as *Bad Practice*, so I changed that to `url(../images/bg.png)` and same for Images inside `misc` folder as `url('../../../../misc/configure.png')` from **CSS** and everything is working as expected.

To tell long story in short, **don't use absolute url from the *root* in CSS** but use relative paths.

Answer (score 0):

CDN module generates for you address like https://cdn.example.com/misc/configure.png but the URL that works is https://cdn.example.com/mysite/misc/configure.png - This means there is a bug in CDN module, in part responsible for URL generation / substitution.

The best, but not fastest course of action would be to report it in [CDN module issue queue](http://drupal.org/project/issues/cdn?categories=All).

Comment: Note: I still think that question is on topic, as determining **if** it was in fact a bug (or if OP simply misconfigured something) was the critical point.

Comment: There wasn't any issue with CDN module, I was doing the wrong practices in Drupal. I had conversation with module creator and corrected the issue according to his suggestion.